# I am missing "ASP.NET Web Project" in my list of Visual Studio 2010 Web project types - how do I get it?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vs-web-application-project

I'm trying to create an "ASP.NET Web Application" project in Visual Studio 2010 but that project type is missing from my File/New/Project dialog:

[image]

I believe it should be part of the standard install, and I don't see it available in the Online Templates.  How can I get that option?

Comment: make sure you install all the service packs too!

Comment: What version of VS 2010 have you installed?

Comment: @Magrands - It's missing both pre- and post-SP1 install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VERY silly mistake - I neglected to install "Visual Web Developer" as part of my VS installation because I misinterpreted it as the Express edition.